# ksh - check if String has a pattern

Tags: shell, scripting, sh, ksh

I have a String of command as below:

```
CMD_LAUNCH="launch.sh \
    -v $ABC_VERSION \
    -p something \
    -X $MAX_HEAP_SPACE_PARAM \
    -Dpersist false \
    -DanotherPasram Abc"
```

I will launch this command in ksh as below:

```
$CMD_LAUNCH
```

How can I make sure the command has `-Dpersist false` ?

I want to cover the cases where there can be any no of spaces between -Dpersist and false. but my attempt fails to accomplish this.

Try 1)

```
if [[ "$CMD_LAUNCH" = *"Dpersist\s+false"* ]]
then
        echo "It's there!"
else
        echo "It's not there!"
fi
```

I want to test if `Dpersist false` is present in command.

Comment: did this using if [[ $ALCYONE_LAUNCHER_CMD = *Dpersist+(' ')false* ]]
is there a better way to represent space than ' ', also how to do I cover tabs as well

Comment: Thanks for input!. tried that it doesn't work.looks like it's not the regex, it's something like pattern in ksh

Comment: Why are you using a string instead of a function in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1:

```
if [[ "$CMD_LAUNCH" == *+(Dpersist+(\s)false)* ]]
then
        echo "It's there!"
else
        echo "It's not there!"
fi
```

Ksh's pattern matching is different to regex as it will always match the whole string - like regex starting with `^` and ending with `$`.
Therefore you have to enclose the pattern, which itself is enclosed in parentheses, with asterisks. The `*` matches any sequence of characters. 
The `+` in front of each pattern means match 1 or more occurrences of the pattern.

### Solution 2:

Another option is to use the `=~` operator:

```
if [[ "$CMD_LAUNCH" =~ Dpersist\s+false ]]                                            
then
    echo "Its there!"
else
     echo "Its not there!"
fi
```

`=~` uses regex syntax.

### Resources

For more examples see

- http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2009/01/ksh93-regular-expressions.html
- http://honglus.blogspot.de/2010/03/regular-expression-in-condition.html
- https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/ch04_05.htm

### Sidenote

Also check out [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/), it helps greatly finding errors in your shell scripts.

Comment: Solution one fails for multiple cases: 1)ksh k.sh "a.sh -Dpersist true false" 2) ksh k.sh "a.sh -Dpersistfalse" 3) ksh k.sh "a.sh"